# How to constraint a C# generic parameter to be of string or X509Certificate2 type?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

How to constraint a C# generic parameter to be of string or X509Certificate2 type?

Basically what I wanted to accomplish here is have a method with generic parameter

```
private void CreateHttprequest<T> (T authenticationContent) where T: string, X509Certificate2
{

   // Common code to create the httpRequest

    if(T is string)
    {
        Add tokenString to the Httprequest header;
    }
    else if(T is X509Certificate2)
    {
        Add the certificate to the HttpRequest header;
    }

    // Common code to add the content to the httpRequest

}
```

I could write 2 overloaded methods for each of the above, but there is common code which could be combined, so I am trying to get it as above.

Please advise.

Here are the 2 methods that I am trying to combine:

```
public HttpWebRequest CreatePostRequest(Uri url, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, Dictionary<string, string> values = null)
    {
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/text";
        httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        httpRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
        httpRequest.Timeout = this.connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds;
        this.AppendHeadersToRequest(httpRequest);

        // Build request content
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            var postData = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            postData.Remove(0, 1);

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

            httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        }

        LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceInformation("Created POST request to {0}", url);
        return httpRequest;
    }


public HttpWebRequest CreatePostRequest(Uri url, string userToken, Dictionary<string, string> values = null)
    {
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/text";
        httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        string authorizationToken = ADFSTokenHelper.SamlTokenBearerName + userToken;
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(ADFSTokenHelper.SamlAuthorizationHeaderName, authorizationToken);

        httpRequest.Timeout = this.connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds;
        this.AppendHeadersToRequest(httpRequest);

        // Build request content
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            var postData = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            postData.Remove(0, 1);

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

            httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        }

        LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceInformation("Created POST request to {0}", url);
        return httpRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Is it really generic if you have to check on the first line? you would be better with 2 methods that both call a base method

Comment: That's not how constraints work

Comment: So it has to be 2 method overloads with different signatures and we cannot really combine both, right? private void Authenticate (string  authenticationContent) and private void Authenticate (X509Certificate2 authenticationContent)

Comment: @SteelBird82 - Why does it? `Authenticate(something){add something to header and call AddCommonRequest();}`, Its hard to give a better answer since we don't know exactly what you are adding and how

Comment: You definitely should just be using two overloads. If there is common code, factor that into a third method used by the other two. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows the entire method and how it's used so that someone can show you how that refactoring can be accomplished.

Comment: Added more details and the actual code. Hope that helps in understanding the problem.

Comment: By the way: if any answer is useful to you, you might consider using the voting buttons to indicate that, if not actually accepting the answer you feel best addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a common method that is called by separate methods, since your method already returns a request you can just add on the certificate after creating the common code

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateHttprequestWithCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    request = CommonRequestMethod();
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Note: You may wish to pass in other parameters too that your common method needs

Comment: That's helps, right its pretty simple, not sure why I was looking at the using generics.

Answer (score 0):

You should factor your two methods into three (or more), where you have overloads for the two specific types you want, and then additional methods to handle the common functionality shared by the two methods.

Based on the code you posted, it might look something like this:

```
HttWebRequest CreateBaseRequest(Uri url)
{
    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/text";
    httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    return httpRequest;
}

void BuildRequestContent(HttpWebRequest httpRequest, Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    httpRequest.Timeout = this.connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds;
    this.AppendHeadersToRequest(httpRequest);

    // Build request content
    if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
    {
        var postData = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        postData.Remove(0, 1);

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequest.ContentLength = 0;
    }

    LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceInformation("Created POST request to {0}", url);
}

public HttpWebRequest CreatePostRequest(Uri url, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, Dictionary<string, string> values = null)
{
    var httpRequest = CreateBaseRequest(url);

    httpRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);

    BuildRequestContent(httpRequest, values);

    return httpRequest;
}

public HttpWebRequest CreatePostRequest(Uri url, string userToken, Dictionary<string, string> values = null)
{
    var httpRequest = CreateBaseRequest(url);

    string authorizationToken = ADFSTokenHelper.SamlTokenBearerName + userToken;
    httpRequest.Headers.Add(ADFSTokenHelper.SamlAuthorizationHeaderName, authorizationToken);

    BuildRequestContent(httpRequest, values);

    return httpRequest;
}
```

Or something like that. Without a complete code example to start with, it's hard to make sure the above is all valid, compiles and runs the way you want. But it's the general idea, if not code you can copy and paste directly into your program.

Comment: That's helps, right its pretty simple, not sure why I was looking at the using generics. Thanks again.